# Getting (default) value from settings bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

I have an IOS5 project.

I have added a settings bundle to my project and added some settings to it.

I set properties of 'host_ip':

```
<dict>
        <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
        <string>None</string>
        <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
        <string>No</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>http://localhost</string>
        <key>IsSecure</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>host_ip</string>
        <key>KeyboardType</key>
        <string>URL</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Host</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
```

I try to read value like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *host = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"host_ip"];
NSLog(@"%@",host);
```

It does not return the default value I set in host_ip, it returns nil.

How can I get my default value?

**UPDATE**

After a user edits a setting, I can retrieve it by the code above. My problem is getting the setting value, if it was not edited by the user yet. As I think in that case it should return the default I set in plist.

Comment: What do you mean "I have added a settings bundle to my project"? Do you mean that you've added a .plist file to your Xcode project? In order to read something from NSUserDefaults, it must be in your app's user defaults, which is generally stored in ~/Library/Preferences/<your app's bundle id>.plist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you register the defaults via `NSUserDefaults`?

See [the `registerDefaults:` method on NSUserDefaults.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults%3a)

Comment: Pls. check my update. It works well if a user had edited a setting, but if it had not been edited, it does not return the default value.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, that's what `-registerDefaults:` is for. It lets you register a dictionary of key/value mappings that are the *default* values for when the user hasn't explicitly provided a value. With this method you can register the same defaults that you listed in your settings bundle.

Comment: I don't understand. I have a DefaultValue key in my plist for all my settings. So why should I register it with register defaults? It is the part of my settings plist, it is in the same file.

Comment: By your suggestions I solved by this: http://ijure.org/wp/archives/179 But it is still not logical for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tom: Because the Settings bundle has *no effect whatsoever* on your running application. Your app doesn't even know it exists. It only gets read by the Settings application. So you need to tell your application what the default values are as well, so it knows how to behave when the user hasn't actually modified any of the preferences yet.